# What should I wear to go and sign an employment contract?

Tags: contracts, company-culture, germany, dress-code

I've finished my interview sessions with a company (2 individual interview days), and also discussed the first draft of the contract with them. They offered me the job, and I've accepted their offer.
Now, I need to go there once more to sign the last version of the contract and start working there from the beginning of the next month.

During the interview sessions, I presented myself there wearing a suit and tie! But, I noticed the company does not have any dress code as most of the employees (even senior ones) wear casual.

So, I was wondering if I can step down from the suit now and appear in normal clothing when I go there to sign my contract?

P.S.: It's an IT company in Germany!

Comment: What kind of work? Tech, financial, artisan, education?

Comment: Would you be going from home, or calling in on your way to/from your current job (or on your lunchbreak)?

Comment: Will you be photographed for an ID card?  Then dress as if you were going to work.  It never hurts to ask if you have questions about the company's attirement environment.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Personally, I believe that overdressing is never an issue.  Wearing a suit may be overkill if the position has already been offered, but perhaps khaki slacks and a button-up shirt would be ideal.  No need for the full suit and tie treatment, but formal enough to continue a good impression and appear professional.

Growing up as the son of an HR Director, he always preached that first impressions are key.  Perhaps you'll be meeting the CEO or a manager that you'll be working under when you go to sign the contract.  In that scenario, I'd recommend a more formal attire.

Comment: Overdressing may get you rejected for being too "formal" when interviewing with a startup.

Comment: @hkBst That's a pretty unlikely scenario and shouldn't be taken into consideration unless the company explicitly states that the interview doesn't require formal attire.  Even then, I'd probably stick to khakis and a polo.  I can't see an interviewee standing out after showing up in a t-shirt and jeans.  You only get one chance to make a first impression.

Comment: @hkBst: I have never (to the best of my knowledge) been rejected for overdressing, and I have had plenty of interviews where I wore a suit, even though I knew the environment was jeans & tee shirts. However, I have known of people who got rejected for going to interviews in casual clothes when something dressier was expected.

Comment: If you're a bit overdressed to begin with, it's easier to "undress" to meet standards than it is to "dress up" once you're already there. i.e. take off a suit coat, loosen a tie, roll up sleeves.

Comment: Seriously, most tech companies these days have a casual dress code, overdressing risks coming off as a poor culture fit.
A nice shirt and smart casual trousers will be fine, but a tie is generally just too far.

Comment: First impressions may be key, but I'm pretty sure I got the next round once because I quickly gauged the environment and slung my blazer over my shoulder...

Comment: @ThomasRedstone You mean most tech companies in Silicon Valley?  That is a very small percentage of tech companies in the world.  I've been to plenty of tech companies that are suit and tie.

Comment: @GreenMatt The "young and hip" companies, aka startups with no one over 30 in employment, put a lot of emphasis on cultural fit and overdressing is one way of not fitting in with the culture. If you're good enough they'll likely not reject you for just that, but if there are other candidates that are equally skilled but they wear what everyone else wears you could definitely be dropped in favour of a more fitting candidate. I usually show up business casual and I know I've gotten a job offer over someone else one time because they thought I would be more in line with my new coworkers.

Comment: @ThomasRedstone: I work at a tech company with a casual dress-code; interviewees still show up in suit, like I did, and I've never heard any interviewer complain about the interviewee being overdressed. It may have been your experience, but it seems far from universal.

Comment: @KevinWessels: So people who say they don't want to be judged by how they dress are judging people by how they dress?

Comment: I've seen people get turned away for being overdressed. It happens. Know the company you're applying to, don't rely on advice from 50 years ago without thinking about it.

Comment: @Erik no one has ever been turned away because they're overdressed.  They get turned away because of other reasons and that gets cited as a reason to avoid lawsuits.  Showing your serious about getting the job is never a problem; showing that you're not going to be able to interact socially with your colleagues is another issue entirely.

Comment: @UKMonkey I was literally there, as a current employee, hearing the judgement "Did you see how he dressed? He's never going to fit in". Not saying it's a good thing, just saying it happens. As this answer says: "first impressions are key". Wearing a suit might be a terrible first impression.

Comment: "Always expect to walk out of the loo and bump into the CEO" is how I try to frame my dress around an office space.

Comment: The comment discussion is a red herring. Overdressing is problematic mainly because/if it makes the wearer feel out of place and uncomfortable. The bad outcomes are virtually always a consequence of poor charisma due to discomfort rather than due to appearing to be “overdressed”. If you can pull off wearing a formal suit in informal company, go for it: James Bond could rock up anywhere without appearing overdressed. On the other hand, if you risk feeling stiff, beware.

Comment: @GreenMatt I can testify to the fact that candidates can and do get rejected for wearing a suit to a tech interview.  Maybe that guy was wearing a suit to compensate for the fact that he wasn't competent enough, or something, but in any case we booted him right out

Comment: If an interviewee showed up in a suit&tie in here (big tech corp in Israel), he would feel very awkward and out of place. I think the OP should dress at the level that his interviewers did during the interviews, and maybe a tiny step up just to be certain.

Comment: I know that the reasons and strategies for hiring people are often enough pseudo science, but I wouldn’t want to work for a company that rejects someone for wearing a suit.

Comment: My take would be that there's no harm in being overdressed for your first interview, because you're trying to make a good first impression. However, once you've seen what other people are wearing you should set your dress style at that level for future contact, because by then it's about trying to fit in.

Answer (score 70):

If you're only going in to sign the contract, you've won the war already. Your employer won't change their mind about hiring you at the last minute just because you show up dressed like everyone else rather than in a suit. You're fine.

Comment: Yes, although it won't hurt to confirm this in an email beforehand, as they might conceivably have clients visiting that day. Ask informally though ("Hey, do I need to be in a suit and tie on day 1?").

Comment: @Justin Asking about dress code when you start a position is perfectly normal and I recommend it if you have doubts. We aren't talking about day 1, we're talking about going in to sign the contract; OP stated that they aren't starting until the beginning of the next month.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. I always find it odd to go from full business to normal. While I agree with the part of the employer not changing their mind about the contract, you can still changed their impression of you. I'd suggest going semi-formal and slowly (think 1, maybe 2 weeks) transition to what you normally wear.

Answer (score 32):

I always prefer to wear business casual at the least on the first day.    Never know if there was a special reason people were wearing casual clothing on the day you interviewed.    Work a day or two, maybe ask what a dress code is, and go from there.   You'll never go wrong by overdressing a bit.

Comment: Ditto. But bring a tie, just in case. I always try to blend in with existing staff (software developers), but slightly neater. If they're in t-shirts, I'll wear a polo shirt or short sleeve button up shirt. etc.

Comment: Rather than "bring a tie, just in case", I'd suggest "wear a tie, just in case". It's not difficult to take the tie off if it's overkill, and generally looks okay after "No one else has a tie, mind if I take mine off?" However, it looks a bit awkward and maybe even presumptuous to put one on after you arrive.

Comment: Anyone who came in wearing a tie, and then brought attention to it by asking about other people's, would get laughed right out of the office anywhere I've ever worked

Answer (score 17):

**Smart casual**

Basically what you would wear if you want out to the movies with friends or whatever, but a small step above that. Namely:

- No offensive clothing
- No dilapidated clothing

You are not going in to work, you are going in to sign some paperwork. Consider it a part of a day off, like going to the post office, or shopping.

The vibe you are trying to give off is one of a person who is neat and tidy when they are in casual attire. You are not trying to give off the vibe of someone who dresses up to sign some paperwork.

On your first day, you should pivot more towards business casual. During the contract signing, you should feel free to ask the representative what the dress code is.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that this is a office type position, wear what you would wear when going to work.

If it's something else, smart casual.

Answer (score 2):

Given your observation, though there is nothing preventing you from wearing smart casuals, signing a(ny) contract is one event where you may want to wear the formals, once again.

It's not about you or anybody else's choice of dressing - it's the event that matters here. Just like, you can wear smart casuals in a board meeting, but usually people chose to dress up in formal attire.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, most of us have been through something like this.  My take on it is that it is fine to dress down *some*, but you still want to present a fresh and professional appearance.  Button on shirt, khaki, navy, gray, or black slacks, etc.  You don't want to stand out in any negative way.

That said, there can be exceptions.  This has happened to both me and my wife:  we got a call in the middle of the day asking us to come in and sign papers that day.  OK (hell yes!!), but that does mean I'm going straight there in blue jeans and a hoodie.

Answer (score -1):

To answer from my own experience as a professional services company owner now, previously an employee for years, both in the US, and being somewhat tuned in to European fashion and work trends, I'd say: if you want to look professional, add your personal mix of tradition and contemporary flair, and still fit in somewhat with a more casual environment, then just ditch the tie. Keep the suit, and pair it with a nice shirt with a small pattern.

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"Just don't ditch the tie. Keep the suit, and don't pair it with a nice shirt with a small pattern."_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Comment: @gnat Fair enough. Edited.

Answer (score -4):

Call and ask.  That's the best way.

Comment: Calling to ask what to wear for a simple contract signing seems like a bit much and would probably be off-putting.

Comment: @Christian only if they were jerks.

Comment: @Tina_Sea Got nothing to do with they are jerks or not. Being a jerk involves words or actions. Them thinking you're a bit strange for being unsure what to wear to sign a piece of paper is quite normal. If I was the boss and my new employee rang to ask what to wear for a contract signing, I'd immediately think: "Working with this fellow is going to be tedious".

Comment: @GregoryCurrie why would you get mad at someone asking a question?

Comment: Tina, @GregoryCurrie didn't say he would get mad.  He said he would think it was a bit strange.  These are not the same thing.  To make the point more clearly, if you went to your manager to ask if you can go to the bathroom, he might not get mad but he sure would think it was weird.

Comment: @Wildcard where I work, you need to ask if you can go to the bathroom.

Comment: @Tina_Sea, for a white collar job, that is crazy.  The only exception I can think of would be a call center.  What type of work do you do?

Comment: @Wildcard I do factory work I'm HOJ right now so I got time to read

Comment: To *ask* in any job is just plain wrong, to make someone aware, fine, but to require permission is just madness.

Comment: @ThomasRedstone yeah, easy to say when you got options

Comment: @Tina_Sea, I can't find a definition for HOJ that seems to fit; what does that stand for?

Comment: @Wildcard HOJ means hurt on the job.I'm out for the rest of the week.

Comment: @Tina_Sea yeah, the USA really does not seem to be a great place for workers rights :-(

Comment: @ThomasRedstone we still got some good unions.  I'm getting paid while I'm out, and the insurance is good.

Comment: Job requirements: "we are looking for someone ... independent, self-driven, ...". You: "I can't decide what to wear. Pls help". Not exactly a good sign.

Comment: Almost all of the companies with a HR division have a manual that explains cultures, rules, dress code and etc. if they hav’t provided such a document. Asking from HR what is the dress code is perfectly fine and I am totally agreed with @Tina_Sea here!

Comment: @Zich asking if there is any dress code would be fine. But since the answer is so short and without any explanation, and after reading the comments, we can only assume that it means to call them specifically to ask what to wear when signing the contract.

Comment: @kapex in that case I completely agree with you because asking so, would looks stupid, but I am still having hope tina didn’t mean that!

Comment: speaking of just asking.  You people could just ask me.

Comment: If you have to call or email anyway to ask for location/time it would not be a problem to ask (if you have not asked in the interview phase) if business casual is ok. If you only ask for the dresscode that might indeed come across a bit strange (but then again if this causes any problem i would consider it a red flag)

Comment: @ThomasRedstone If you are in a high throughput factory, you ask. And that's not crazy, but perfectly reasonable, you don't want the production line to hold because some worker that is required just left and stuff is missing a production step into the next stage. Yes, the assumption would be your boss finds a short time replacement or tells you when the next break fits well. If you can directly get a replacement that's also fine in the places I know, but that's not always the case, i.e. everyone in direct sight has their own post.